# Dukt Twitter Plugin, problem with "search/tweets" or request to Twitter REST API

Tags: plugin-dukttwitter

we're using the Dukt Twitter plugin 0.9.25 and it works fine with calling the user's timeline:

```
    {% set tweets = craft.twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', {count:1}) %}
```

If we request any other data like

```
    {% set tweets = craft.twitter.get('search/tweets', {q:'#craftcms',}) %}
```

we're receiving two tweets which are empty. Anyone else having these problems and found a solution?

Thanks, Lars

Comment: Not used the plugin but try %23 instead of #

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested this works on my install:

```
{% set tweets = craft.twitter.get('search/tweets', {q:'#craftcms'}) %}

{% for tweet in tweets.statuses %}
    {{ tweet.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Have you tried running a `{{ dump(tweets) }}` to see what you get?

Comment: Thanks, it works. It didn't work cause of a stupid bug in my code.